# How to set what views should resize after constraints are satisfied?

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout

When all Auto Layout constraints are satisfied while resizing a window, how can I specify which view is preferred to be resized?

For example, I would like to resize view A instead of view B when the window below changes its size. [image]

If I do nothing, view B is resized instead of view A. [image]

What I want is for view A to be resized instead of view B.

Thank you very much! ;-)

Comment: Please have a look at [this post by Bridgeyman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11246811/356895) and [this answer by codingFriend1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12109366/356895).

Comment: If you found a solution yourself please post it as an answer to share it with the community.